# Error al instanciar en Eclipse JAVA

Tags: java, eclipse, objeto

cuando creo instancias para conectar mi clase "a" a mi clase "b" y viceversa no me marca ningún error al escribirlo, pero al momento de compilar me sale un error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError"

```
package PAQUETE1;

import PAQUETE2.b;

public class a {
    b objetoB= new b();
    public int  a=0;
    
    public void imprimir() {
        System.out.println("EL NUMERO ES---> "+a);
    }
}
```

Esta es la clase "b":

```
package PAQUETE2;

import java.util.Scanner;

import PAQUETE1.a;

public class b {
    Scanner capturar= new Scanner(System.in);
    a objetoA= new a();
    public void capturar() {
        System.out.println("INGRESE UN NUMERO");
        objetoA.a=capturar.nextInt();
        objetoA.imprimir();
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: te falta agregar el método main en tu clase b

Comment: Lo tengo en otra clase package PAQUETE2;

public class main {
 public static void main (String[] args) {
  b objetoB= new b();
  objetoB.capturar();
  
 }
}

Comment: borra el objeto b en tu clase a ,eso esta causando el stackoverflow

Comment: Pero entonces como recibo en A el valor